# Binding Angularjs data outside the ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a general template for all pages which contains a menu bar and it is outside the `ng-view`.From one of my page which is inside the `ng-view` i want to bind input data to this template area(this area is under a different controller than the input page).I mean when i will enter name,the name will appear to the template area.Is it possible ?
Here is the [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WH8DkjCKNLbGt1hGoRd0?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="sampleApp">

  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        name is :{{name}}<br/>
  username is :{{uname}}
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#name"> Add name </a></li>
          <li><a href="#uname"> add username </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with ng-switch.
>
> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use
>
> ```
> <input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> rather than 
> <input type="text" ng-model="prop1">.
> ```
>
> [— AngularJS Wiki - What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance?](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/pzqYT6CadHGDyqccE34k?p=preview)

---

*`$scope.obj` is working like a `$rootScope` variable. Is it for prototypal inheritance?*

Scopes are arranged in hierarchical structure which mimic the DOM structure of the application. Each AngularJS application has exactly one root scope, but may have any number of child scopes.

```
ng-app --> $rootScope
 |- ng-controller --> $scope (container)
    |- ng-view      --> $scope (view)
```

By using: `<input ng-model="obj.name" />` the `ng-model` directive in the view controller uses prototypical inheritance to find `$scope.obj` from outside the view. It can then get and set the `name` property of that object.

[image]

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-hierarchies)

---

> ## `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil
>
> Scopes in AngularJS form a hierarchy, prototypically inheriting from a root scope at the top of the tree. Usually this can be ignored, since most views have a controller, and therefore a scope, of their own.
>
> Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject `$rootScope` and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like `ng-show` just like values on your local `$scope`.
>
> Of course, global state sucks and you should use `$rootScope` sparingly, like you would (hopefully) use with global variables in any language. In particular, don't use it for code, only data. If you're tempted to put a function on `$rootScope`, it's almost always better to put it in a service that can be injected where it's needed, and more easily tested.
>
> Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data.
>
> [— AngularJS FAQ - `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)

Comment: $scope.obj is working like a $rootScope variable .Is it for   prototypal inheritance?

Answer (score 1):

Angular's $rootScope can be used to share information between the app's components (besides other uses).  It is discouraged to rely upon it too much because it could become polluted or difficult to trace up and down the app's entire scope 'stack'.  But if you really need or want to set 'global' data, it works:

In your new plunkr, you are using both ng-model and ng-value for the text input. Remove the ng-value altogether. (It is used typically for elements that have 'value' properties, like radio buttons and checkboxes, where the 'value' is 'checked' or 'selected', etc.)  ng-model is what you want.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DnzOdRicXLHtg4DqoVdJ?p=preview

```
name is :{{$root.name}}
username is :{{$root.uname}}
```

and

```
Name: <input ng-model="$root.name">
<h1>You entered: {{$root.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: don't know why but the ng-value is not working now !

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing an ng-value

Comment: sorry, i have updated both the question and plunker!

Comment: ng-value is tripping it up.  See my revised answer+plunkr.

Comment: Thanks for you effort but in this case rootScope can be little bit odd as it will be vanished after the page reload!

Comment: You never mentioned that as a requirement.