# AngularJS 1.5 file Upload is working in IE/Chrome while debugging

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, binary

I have written code which will take base64 data from angularjs and pass into.Net for Binary conversion. It is working fine in my system. I have deployed code into server. and Byte array is going NULL but alert msg is coming successfull. But If i am putting debugger in console, It is working perfectly menaing byte content is going. Not understanding what I did wrong. First I am putting fileobject into rootscope variable while browsing. and upload button hit parsing the file and saving into db.  Please help me.
HTML Code

```
<div class="col-sm-4">  
<input filestyle="" file-model = "signatureImage" name="signatureImage" type="file"  accept=".png" />                                   
 </div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
<button type="button" ng-click="apc.uploadFile()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="icon-cloud-upload mr"></span>Upload
</button>
</div>
```

In Angularjs,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ba')
        .directive('fileModel', ['$parse','$rootScope', function ($parse, $rootScope) {           
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;               
                element.bind('change', function () {                    
                    scope.$apply(function () {                        
                        var UserInfoID = sessionStorage.getItem('UserInfoId'); 
                        var DataVariable = "signatureImage_" + UserInfoID;                        
                        $rootScope[DataVariable] = element[0].files[0];
                       //modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ba')
        .controller('APC', APC);

    APC.$inject = ['$http', '$scope', 'ngDialog', 'DTOptionsBuilder', '$filter', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$localStorage'  ];
    function APC($http, $scope, ngDialog, DTOptionsBuilder, $filter, $rootScope, $timeout, $localStorage) {

  vm.uploadFile= function () {
            var UserInfoID = sessionStorage.getItem('UserInfoId');
            var DataVariable = "signatureImage_" + UserInfoID;
            var file = $rootScope[DataVariable];
            var UserName = vm.NewPersonInfo.UserName;            
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            var fileData = reader.result;
            fileData = fileData.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");           
            var uploadData = {
                    Name: file.name,
                    FileType: fileData,
                    UserInfoID: UserName
                }
            $http.post('api/AP/USA', uploadData)
                    .then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (response != null && response.data != null) {
                            alert("Digital Successfully Uploaded.");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Digital Successfully Upload Failed!!!");
                        }
                    });
        };
 }
})();
```

and .net code is as follows

```
[HttpPost]
        public DataSet USA(apc.ImageModel imageModel)
        {
            ResultSet dsSaveDoc = null;

            imageModel.Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageModel.FileType);
            imageModel.FileType = "image/png";
//DB Calling
}
```

Now, here `imageModel.Bytes` is going NULL without putting debugger, If i am putting debugger it is working fine in server.

Please help me....

Comment: It is better to send files directly than to convert them to base64. If you must use base64, the FormData API is more efficient. See [How to POST binary files with AngularJS (with upload DEMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432354/how-to-post-binary-files-with-angularjs-with-upload-demo/45433364#45433364)

Comment: A directive that stores its results on $rootScope is not wise. Consider using a directive that works with the ngModelController. See [ng-model for <input type=“file”/> (with directive DEMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063000/ng-model-for-input-type-file-with-directive-demo/43074638#43074638). See also [$rootScope exists, but it can be used for evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836870/binding-angularjs-data-outside-the-ng-view/44838375#44838375).

Comment: Because from APC controller scope, I am not getting file Object from setting value from directive scope. I have checked Scope id is different for both the scenario, so i used for rootscope to avoid it. but When i am putting debugger in "vm.uploadFile" it is working perfectly in Chrome as well as IE. but removing debugger same code sending NULL in Stored procedure...I am saving BLOB (varbinary) into DB.

Comment: Read [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs). New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.